# "call setup.bat" issue in ROS 2 humble install on windows 10

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-humble

I am trying to install ROS 2 on windows 10.
I went through the setup guide without any issues and errors until the stage of

> **"Environment setup**

> Start a command shell and source the ROS 2 setup
> file to set up the workspace:
>
> call C:\dev\ros2_humble\local_setup.bat"

It throws me the error:

> call : Die Benennung "call" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines
> ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern
> enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
> In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1

call C:\dev\ros2_humble\local_setup.bat

- ```
   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (call:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

and if I run it as cmd it is:

> "[rti_connext_dds_cmake_module][warning] RTI Connext DDS environment script not found (\resource\scripts\rtisetenv_x64Win64VS2017.bat). RTI Connext DDS will not be available at runtime, unless you already configured PATH manually."

I don't get what is missing. Do I need to execute "call" in a specific folder or do I lack a package? I am quite blind in this area and this is a rookie question. Thus, if I may, please be detailed in your answer ;)

Thanks a lot and any help is greatly appreciated.